# combine elements on form

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I've got two rectangles and an ellipse. How to combine them and use the same animation on new combined element?

```
<Rectangle Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="220,235,0,0" Name="rectangle2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="38" Fill="LightGreen" />
<Ellipse Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,269,0,0" Name="ellipse1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Fill="Yellow" />
<Ellipse Height="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,266,0,0" Name="ellipse2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17" Fill="#FF58FF00" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want fixed size elements, moved relative to each other, then place them in a canvas and use canvas coordinates to position them.

A canvas has a low overhead for rendering as it displays nothing but its child elements, in pixel offsets, and has no complex calculation of margins or rows.

The equivalent of your example is:

```
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,235,0,145" Width="246">
        <Rectangle Height="100" x:Name="rectangle2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="38" Fill="LightGreen" Canvas.Left="208" />
        <Ellipse Height="23" x:Name="ellipse1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" Fill="Yellow" Canvas.Left="215" Canvas.Top="34" />
        <Ellipse Height="17" x:Name="ellipse2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17" Fill="#FF58FF00" Canvas.Top="31" />
    </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Group into T:Panel.
Usually I'm grouping in Canvas first, then in Viewbox (Fill ot Fit) second.